# UAC "Yes" button is disabled, but I am logged on as an administrator

Tags: windows-7, administrator, uac

Im trying to run an installer on my Win7 laptop but the UAC "Yes" button is disabled.  Even if I select "Run as Administrator" I cannot get past this prompt.

What can I do from here?

[image: Prompt screenshot]

Comment: Policy settings restricts running of unsigned files?

Comment: @Maximus - Not sure, how can I check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had disabled the administrator account and made my 'regular' user a guest user on the system,

Here is how I fixed it:

1) Reboot into Safe mode

2) Start elevated command prompt and run this command which enables administrator account.

```
    net user administrator /active:yes
```

3) Reset the administrator password.

```
    net user administrator password
```

4) Rebooted and logged on as 'Administrator'

5) Start another elevated command prompt and add my regular user to the 'administrators' group

```
net localgroup Administrator [YOURUSERID] /add
```

6) Reboot and login as your normal user and everything should be good to go.